# ASP.Net Web API Post Command not saves values

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, fiddler

i have created new ASP.Net Web API project using Visual studio 2015 and while testing **POST** command through **Fiddler** i get response of 201 no content.
After that when i use **GET** command on fiddler the new value is not saved.
i am not publishing it just running in debug mode.

```
    static List<string> Strings = new List<string>() {
        "value0", "value1", "value2"
    };

 // GET api/values
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return Strings;
    }

 // POST api/values
    public void Post([FromBody]string value)
    {
        Strings.Add(value);
    }
```

Comment: can you please add the client side code (the one sending the post request)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is because there is no return value `void`

As per the asp.net:

https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/action-results

> If the return type is void, Web API simply returns an empty HTTP response with status code 204 (No Content).

Answer (score 0):

Your code worked for me and added to the list. Make sure you are sending with content type `application/json` as `'the string'` (I used Postman to test the POST).

You will get the  201 because the Get method is void but this will not mean POST is not working. If you want something back you could change return type to something like `IHttpActionResult` and `return Ok(Strings)`, after the Add to list, which will return the list and a 200 status. You could even put some code in to check list add worked then return either Ok() or BadRequest().